# Generating draw commands and data for them in compute shader the right way

Tags: graphics, glsl

Helli, right now I have this block of code I am struggling with:

```
        uint InstanceIdx = atomicAdd(IndirectDrawIndexedCommands[CommandIdx].InstanceCount, 1);

        IndirectDrawIndexedCommands[CommandIdx].IndexCount    = MeshOffsets[CommandIdx].IndexCount;
        IndirectDrawIndexedCommands[CommandIdx].FirstIndex    = MeshOffsets[CommandIdx].IndexOffset;
        IndirectDrawIndexedCommands[CommandIdx].VertexOffset  = 0; //int(MeshOffsets[CommandIdx].VertexOffset);
        IndirectDrawIndexedCommands[CommandIdx].FirstInstance = 0; 
        IndirectDrawIndexedCommands[CommandIdx].DrawID        = CommandIdx;

        MeshOffsets[CommandIdx].InstanceOffset = CommandIdx == 0 ? 0 : IndirectDrawIndexedCommands[CommandIdx - 1].InstanceCount;

        InstanceIdx += MeshOffsets[CommandIdx].InstanceOffset;
        MeshDrawCommands[InstanceIdx].MeshIndex    = CommandIdx;
        MeshDrawCommands[InstanceIdx].Translate = MeshDrawCommandData[DrawIndex].Translate;
        MeshDrawCommands[InstanceIdx].Scale     = MeshDrawCommandData[DrawIndex].Scale;
        MeshDrawCommands[InstanceIdx].Rotate    = MeshDrawCommandData[DrawIndex].Rotate;
```

Basically, I want this block of code to work like this: imagine I have 2 meshes. This 2 meshes will represent IndirectDrawIndexedCommands data. So, if I have 2 mashes, then CommandIdx will be only 0 and 1. IndirectDrawIndexedCommands is just basically for indirect draw calls. MeshDrawCommands is represents the data for each instance of the mesh. Basically, if I have 256 mesh draw data for each mesh, then it would have 256 instances per each mesh.

I want to make a solution like this: when I am going through instance data of 1, then all the data should come into first half of the MeshDrawCommands. But when I am going through instance data of second mesh, then, by that time, I want IndirectDrawIndexedCommands[0].InstanceCount to have 256 in its memory, so that all instance data would come into second half of the MeshDrawCommands.

Right now I am struggling to correctly generate the instance data for draw calls and willing to do it in one pass. I was thinking about parallel sum, but I don't really see how it could fit here